# how to change sprite ( Source sprite ) in UI Image using a script | unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

how to change source sprite to regular sprite in ui image using a script?

[image]

I searched in the unity documentation and on youtube but there was no information on new versions

Comment: Use the `sprite` property: https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Image-sprite.html

Answer (score 1):

You can change the sprite by just assigning the new sprite to the sprite Property on the image like this:

```
public class SpriteChange : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Sprite newSprite;
    public void ChangeSprite()
    {
        var image = GetComponent<Image>();
        image.sprite = newSprite;
    }
}
```

for this you obviously need a reference to the sprite you want loaded.

unity documentation for [Image.sprite](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.Image-sprite.html) and [Image](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.Image.html) from UIElements
or if you use UGUI the same links for [Image.sprite](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UI.Image.html) and [Image](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/api/UnityEngine.UI.Image.html#UnityEngine_UI_Image_sprite)

Answer (score 0):

To do that first you need to add the following directive in order to have access to the [UI Image](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UIElements.Image.html) component:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

Now what you need, is to create a reference of your Image component

```
public Image uiImage;
```

You can drag and drop your `Image` into the script component from your Unity editor or you can use the [GameObject.GetComponent<>()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) method in your `Start()` method. After that you can change the sprite of your UI Image like the following.

```
void Start()
{
    uiImage = GetComponent<Image>();
    uiImage.sprite = sprite;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Unity version 2021.3.8f1, I could not use Image in component selection even though I had the namespace 'UnityEngine.UI' used. Visual Studio just blurred the using namespace saying it was unnecessary. What?!

So I had to do this.

```
gameObj.GetComponent<UnityEngine.UI.Image>().sprite = imgSprite;
```

where gameObj => the game object containing the image holder
and imgSprite => the game object containing the sprite image

and it worked for me.